# Java try catch and finally. If exception occurs will finally still hold the reference?

Tags: java

**Code:**

```
  try {

          dbConnection = jdbcTemplate.getDataSource().getConnection();
          callableStatement = dbConnection.prepareCall(getDBUSERCursorSql);
        }
    catch (SQLException e) {
      LOGGER.error("Error occured", e);
    }
    finally
    {
        if (dbConnection != null && !dbConnection.isClosed()) {
                    dbConnection.close();
         }
    }
```

So if the exception occurs in line callableStatement = dbConnection.prepareCall(getDBUSERCursorSql); and the catch block executes, will the reference to `dbConnection` still exist in finally block? Fortify says no but I am not sure if fortify is correct.

Comment: nope, since the exception will be thrown before assignment

Comment: I think as long as `dbConnection` is defined outside of the `try catch` block it will still exist. Give it a try? :)

Comment: @EM-Creations the question is not about variable being available, its about the reference to dbConnection:)

Comment: @JohnnyAW The question says: "will the reference to dbConnection still exist", the answer is.. yes as long as it's declared outside the `try catch`, what that contents of that variable might be is another question.

Comment: @JohnnyAW - try {

          dbConnection = jdbcTemplate.getDataSource().getConnection(); callableStatement = dbConnection.prepareCall(getDBUSERCursorSql); 
        } Imagine that the exception occurs as a result of callableStatement = dbConnection.prepareCall(getDBUSERCursorSql); . So now will the ref to dbConnection  be available?

Comment: @HariRao yes, your variable `dbConnection` will hold the reference to the connection-object and you need to close it in the finally-block

Answer (score 2):

If the `dbConnection` variable is declared prior to the try block, it will be available in the finally block. Now, whether or not its value will be null or not depends on the code of the try block. If the only code that can throw an exception is the `dbConnection = jdbcTemplate.getDataSource().getConnection();` line, it will probably be null if that line throws an exception.

For example, the following code is valid :

```
Connection dbConnection = null;
try {
    dbConnection = jdbcTemplate.getDataSource().getConnection();
    callableStatement = dbConnection.prepareCall(getDBUSERCursorSql);
}
catch (SQLException e) {
  LOGGER.error("Error occured", e);
}
finally
{
    if (dbConnection != null && !dbConnection.isClosed()) {
         dbConnection.close();
    }
}
```

If, on the other hand, you declare `dbConnection` inside the try block, your code won't pass compilation.

EDIT:

If `callableStatement = dbConnection.prepareCall(getDBUSERCursorSql);` throws an exception, the finally block will have a reference to the Connection instance referred by `dbConnection`, and will be able to close the connection.

Comment: Yes Connection "dbConnection = null;" is declared prior to try

Comment: the question is about the reference to the dbConnection, not about the variable itself

Comment: @JohnnyAW `dbConnection` in itself is something that can be referenced. That's what the question asks.

Comment: @JohnnyAW I'm assuming that the try block does something with the `dbConnection` variable beside initializing it. Otherwise this entire try-catch-finally block does nothing interesting. If you run some query/update statement on the connection which throws an exception, the finally block will have a reference to the connection and should probably close the connection (and perhaps rollback the transaction).

Comment: @Eran try/catch in the question is initializing the connection, nothing else, he should already know, that the variable is visible, since he tries to close it in the finally-block. I think the question is about variable holding reference to connection object

Comment: @JohnnyAW You can't always assume that the OP posted the entire code. In this case, I assumed the real code contains more statements in the try block, since it would make no sense to have a try-catch-finally block that initializes a connection and closes it right away, without doing anything with it.

Comment: Yup I am just interested in knowing if  variable - dbConnection holding reference to connection object.

Answer (score 1):

[The finally Block](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/finally.html):

> The finally block always executes when the try block exits. This
>   ensures that the finally block is executed even if an unexpected
>   exception occurs.

So, yes. The reference to `dbConnection` still exists in finally block if it does not lose its scope within the previous `try` block.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks guys. Yes finally has the reference. I think I should have tried the following by myself in the first instance

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String msg ="StringIsNotNull";
        printThis(msg);

    }

    private static void printThis(String msg){
        try{
            System.out.println(msg);
            throw new Exception();
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        finally{
            System.out.println(msg);
            msg=null;
        }

    }
```

When I ran the above, I got the following

StringIsNotNull

java.lang.Exception

StringIsNotNull